# how to convert the in date when len of int is greater than 17 in SQL

Tags: sql-server

The int value is '1192060800000000' then following `select` statement works properly ie. length 16

```
SELECT DATEADD(day,clinicaldate/1000000/3600/24,'01-01-1960') FROM document
```

Refered - https://www.qvera.com/kb/index.php/743/can-change-clinicaldate-from-centricity-document-into-date

If the length is greater than or equal to '18' and having (-) minus sign at the beginning of the `int` (-58635680520000000) 
then it gives the following error-

> 'Adding a value to a 'datetime' column caused an overflow'

I would like to know how I can ge the result for 18 digit int or how can we exclude such records in the query?

Comment: "If the length is greater than or equal to '18'" -- the length of what, exactly?

Comment: Rather than giving a value that works, gives us a value that doesn't and the expected value.

Comment: @Larnu, it's -58635680520000000 which gives an error.

Comment: What date are you expecting for `-58635680520000000`? What is the logic for turning `-58635680520000000` into date *`xxxx-xx-xx`*?

Comment: You are going to have to explain things here more clearly. Those values cannot possibly be ints. They are WAY too large for the int datatype. But the biggest question is why are you storing dates like this in the first place? We have the date and datetime datatypes to handle storing this type of information.

Comment: @Sean, You are correct. Basically, GE centricity EMR has the table 'Document' and they provided the column 'Clinicaldate' to their client whose datatype is 'Number' in Oracle. I want to convert it into Date in SQL Server.

Comment: You are going to have to explain things here more clearly. I don't know this software and you are not adding any explanation to the question. I am not good at guessing what people want. If you can explain the logic I can help.

Answer (score 0):

cast(clinicaldate as varchar(20)), use substring() to extract the section you actually want to work with, then do your math.